# Reuse a cloudfoundry app without having to rebuild from sratch

Tags: django, celery, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, django-celery

I deploy a Django Application with Cloudfoundry. Building the app takes some time, however I need to launch the application with different start commands and the only solution I have today is fully to rebuild each time the application.

With Docker, changing the start command is very easy and it doesn't require to rebuild to the whole container, there must be a more efficient way to do this:

Here are the applications launched:

- **FrontEndApp-Prod:** The Django App using gunicorn
- **OrchesterApp-Prod:** The Django Celery Camera & Heartbeat
- **WorkerApp-Prod:** The Django Celery Workers

All these apps are basically identical, they just use different routes, configurations and start commands.

Below is the file `manifest.yml` I use:

```
defaults: &defaults
  timeout: 120
  memory: 768M
  disk_quota: 2G
  path: .
  stack: cflinuxfs2
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/buildpack-python.git
  services:
  - PostgresDB-Prod
  - RabbitMQ-Prod
  - Redis-Prod

applications:

- name: FrontEndApp-Prod
  <<: *defaults
  routes:
  - route: www.myapp.com
  instances: 2
  command: chmod +x ./launch_server.sh && ./launch_server.sh

- name: OrchesterApp-Prod
  <<: *defaults
  memory: 1G
  instances: 1
  command: chmod +x ./launch_orchester.sh && ./launch_orchester.sh
  health-check-type: process
  no-route: true

- name: WorkerApp-Prod
  <<: *defaults
  instances: 3
  command: chmod +x ./launch_worker.sh && ./launch_worker.sh
  health-check-type: process
  no-route: true
```

Comment: Why aren't you pushing the three apps separately? Aren't they run concurrently? Add more details on how the system should look like. Is this with a devops cycle?

Comment: I could absolutely do what you say. However, for me it is still sub-optimal. They all share the same "container" just executed with a different start command. I'm sure I can build the boilerplate, and then modify the start command, route, memory, number of instances accordingly to the app need.

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of for this:

1. You can use some of the new v3 API features and take advantage of their support for multiple processes in a `Procfile`.  With that, you'd essentially have a `Profile` like this:

   ```
   web: ./launch_server.sh
   worker: ./launch_orchester.sh
   worker: ./launch_worker.sh
   ```

   The platform should then stage your app once, but deploy it three times based on the droplet that is produced from staging. It's slick because you end up with only one application that has multiple processes running off of it. The drawback is that this is a experimental API at the time of me writing this, so it still has some rough edges, plus the exact support you get could vary depending on how quickly your CF provider installs new versions of the Cloud Controller API.

   You can read all the details about this here:

   https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/build-cf-push-learn-procfiles/
2. You can use `cf local`. This is a cf cli plugin which allows you to build a droplet locally (staging occurs in a docker container on your local machine). You can then take that droplet and deploy it as much as you want.

   The process would look roughly like this, you'll just need to fill in some options/flags (*hint* run `cf local -h` to see all the options):

   - `cf local stage`
   - `cf local push FrontEndApp-Prod`
   - `cf local push OrchesterApp-Prod`
   - `cf local push WorkerApp-Prod`

   The first command will create a file ending in `.droplet` in your current directory, the subsequent three commands will deploy that droplet to your provider and run it.  The net result is that you should end up with three applications, like you have now, that are all deployed from the same droplet.

   The drawback is that your droplet is local, so you're uploading it three times once for each app.

I suppose you also have a third option which is to just use a docker container. That has it's own advantages & drawbacks though.

Hope that helps!